# array of multipart file at time with spring boot

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spring-boot, axios, multipartform-data

[enter image description here][1]add multiple multipart files :-

```
 {
          this.state.imageUploads.map((image, index) => {
            return (
              <Fragment key={index}>
                <input type="file" name="myFile" onChange={this.onImageUpload(index)} />
              </Fragment>
            )
          })
        }
```

functions and axios call

```
onFileChangeHandler = e => {
e.preventDefault()
let imageUploads = this.state.imageUploads.concat([''])
this.setState({ imageUploads })}

onImageUpload = i => e => {
let imageUploads = [...this.state.imageUploads]
imageUploads[i] = e.target.files[0]
this.setState({ imageUploads })}

imageUploadSubmit = (productId) => {
let file = this.state.imageUploads
console.log("----this.state.imageUploads[0]---at index 0----------", this.state.imageUploads[0])
let token = localStorage.getItem("token")
let formData = new FormData();

formData.append('myfile', file)
try {
  Axios.post("/file/upload", formData,
    {
      headers: {
        'authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
      }

    },
    {
      body: { data: formData }
    })
    .then(res => {
      const json = res.data;
      console.log("--------------after upload reasponse--------", json)
    })
} catch (err) {
  this.setState({
    error: "error in register"
  })}}
```

Back end - spring boot controller ----

```
@PostMapping(value="/upload", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public void uploadFile(@RequestParam("myfile") MultipartFile[] myfile) throws IOException {

    System.out.println("-----Test--myfile.size---"+myfile.length);
    System.out.println("-----Test---myfile--"+myfile);}[enter image description here][1]
```

when trying to upload this - then in request - i got this istead of multipart file or else which cn be accept by my backend code --

```
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Oh1sEQbVCEOjuNpE0tkPRxTJKLoaaqPs
```

i have tried object class as received param in controller  then i get the data in object form but how can i deal with it  ??
i tried single multipart file thats works fine - but i have to pass multiple multipart file - ?!!

Comment: thankyou - but it's done  .... :)

Comment: What did you do? My problem is very similar.

Comment: asking about backend or client side ?

Comment: @JeanWillianS.J. ?

Comment: Hello, I guess both parts would be interesting. Could you edit your question and post the solution you found?